# Facebook app canvas setSize and setAutoGrow no longer working while logged in

Tags: facebook, facebook-apps

Our FB tab app canvas no longer auto adjusts height as it should when logged in. Hitting app tab while logged out auto adjusts height as expected.

We use `FB.Canvas.setSize()` on each page load, so a page change will trigger auto size. I have also tried `FB.Canvas.setAutoGrow()`. Both fail while logged in.

I tried a version of Chrome from a couple years ago and same issue so doesn't appear to be browser security changes lately. Something I noticed for authenticated users versus unauthenticated is that the the former has the app loaded in an additional iframe layer.

Based on [docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Canvas.setAutoGrow) our current fixed height setting of 800 should allow at least setAutoGrow to function. I am able to call setSize successfully in devtools but there is no effect of size while logged in, only while logged out.

Here is a representation of the code. I have added console log calls and confirmed the fbAsyncInit code is running.

Any work around here or known issues currently?

```
<script>
    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        FB.init({
            appId : 'xxxxxxxxx',
            status : true,
            cookie : true,
            xfbml : true,
            oauth: true
        });
        
        FB.Canvas.setSize();
        FB.Canvas.scrollTo(0,0);

        FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
            ...
        }
    };
    (function() {
        var e = document.createElement('script'); e.async = true;
        e.src = document.location.protocol +
        '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
        document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
      }());
</script>
```

Comment: Relatively current (Dec 2020) bug report, were people say it does not work with the “new layout”, might be related: https://developers.facebook.com/support/bugs/807515483352790/ But they are saying there that fixing it is not currently a priority.

Comment: Not sure if that’s the same reason/issue you are having here, a difference between logged in/out is not mentioned in there. (But then who knows whether any of the people reporting there, explicitly tested that.) You can file your own bug report if you like, but it might get closed as a duplicate, or get a similar “no fix now” response.

Comment: @CBroe I found that page shortly before you posted, but if you want to add that as an answer I'll accept it. Since the app is not critical for us we have just added a css change to allow scrolling in the iframe and increased our default app height, though the latter has not taken effect in our app yet after a couple hours.

Comment: I don’t think just referring to the bug report warrants an actual answer. _“though the latter has not taken effect in our app yet after a couple hours”_ - that sounds like a simple caching issue though?

Comment: @CBroe based on FB stating they will never fix and this involving an iframe coordinating with a parent of another domain, I don't expect there to ever be a workaround here. That is why I thought a bug report indicating it will never be fixed would be the proper answer. I could add a more thorough answer regarding overflow scroll and app height in addition to mention of bug. I assume as well that the height not updating is a server-side caching issue, but I would also expect an app setting to make it through to the cache after multiple hours. I guess I'll just have to wait and see.

Comment: Yes, if you add some more info on what you did to work around the issue, that would make sense as an answer. That would make it have a bit more “flesh”, than me just referring to the bug report, and not much else. And “self-answers” are officially encouraged here in situations where that is applicable and makes sense, so go ahead!